# Unavailable exception while trying to retrieve data from Cassandra

Tags: node.js, nosql, cassandra

I have a Cassandra DB and am creating a column family as follows.

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY users
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND column_metadata = [
{column_name: username, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: city, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type="KEYS"}
];
```

I am inserting data into the column family using the following in node.js

```
var cql = "INSERT INTO App.users(KEY,username,city) VALUES (?,?,?)";
cassandra.execute(cql,[json.username+(new Date().getTime()),json.username,
    json.city], function(err, rows) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

This executes properly, but suppose I use cassandra-cli and run

```
 get user where city='NYC';
```

I get an unavailable exception. The following is the CQL query which I have in my node.js script which throws the same exception.

```
var cql = "SELECT notes,heading FROM App.users where city=?";
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? I have made a secondary index on the city column, I hope that is correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many nodes do you have?  Are any unavailable?  Are any nodes listed as down when running 'nodetool status'?

Comment: I have a single node, as of yet. Let me check the nodetool status command.

Comment: Is it a mistake from your side or a typo... `get users where city='NYC'`

Comment: What is your replication factor for your keyspace?

Comment: well in that case can you tell me in `get user where city='NYC';` what is `user`? i guess you have `users` as your CF... And also let me know about your RF. May be you can provide me the `desc keyspace` output from cqlsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Abhi for your suggestion. The link was really helpful, so I created the keyspace in the following manner and it worked properly.

```
create keyspace App with placement_strategy ='org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' 
   and strategy_options = {replication_factor:2};
```

I have connected 2 computers to my cassandra cluster, hence the replication_factor is set to 2.

Comment: I don't think it will work properly, as you have RF equals to 2 and you said earlier you are working on a single node.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, i added another computer to the cluster.

Comment: Well apart from this, i am using a node.js client created by rackspace for inserting and select rows from Cassandra. The insert works properly, but the select is running in with problems. Do you have any idea whats  wrong. This is the error thread I am referring to https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client/issues/28#issuecomment-18187696

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a keyspace creation issue. Check your keyspace creation schema properly. May be this [discussion on cassandra user group](http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/UnavailableException-for-keyspace-td7585739.html) will give you a better idea

Comment: Make sure you mark the answer as solved so someone else who comes by will know this is correct. Thanks!